# update notification in WP app

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want create update notification in my wp app, that when I will publish new version my app in main screen displayed pop-up with text  available new version.

How I can do it? 
Can I get data about last version my app from market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/07/24/checking-for-updates-from-inside-a-windows-phone-app/ for code that checks if there is a newer version available.
See http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/09/zero-lines-of-code-solution-for-in-app.html for easy integration in your app.